# XCTest Objective C Xcode8.1 how to extract label/value/name of any button or navigator bar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xctest

Can anyone tell me how to extract label/value/name of any button or navigator bar

code I have tried so far

```
NSString *Test = app.navigationBars[@"Test"].staticTexts[@"Test"].title;
NSLog(@"%@++++++++", Test);
```

and

```
NSString *Test = app.navigationBars[@"Test"].staticTexts[@"Test"].accessibilityLabel;
NSLog(@"%@++++++++", Test);
```

and

```
NSString *Test = app.navigationBars[@"Test"].staticTexts[@"Test"].accessibilityValue;
NSLog(@"%@++++++++", Test);
```

Output remains null for all the 3 above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `label` to access the value of a static text element.

```
NSString *test = app.navigationBars[@"Test"].staticTexts[@"Test"].label;
NSLog(@"%@++++++++", test);
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xcuielementattributes/1500692-label

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use `label`. For your case replace this as :

```
NSString *Test = app.navigationBars[@"Test"].staticTexts[@"Test"].label;
```